# Does Oracle have any feature filter similar CONSTRAINT but on select query?

Tags: oracle

In my scenario the existing application software complex and many modules being called table `tbl_company_info` since company has changed to new address need to keep old info for reference invoice but also need apply new info for next invoice. Because update table columns or insert new row(address) or update query will costly and time. My question any feature similar  CONSTRAINT that could internal apply for? e.g auto check filter when SELECT `tbl_company_info`​ will return new inf(address) base on criteria `sysdate`.
The benefit no update existing SQL query, no update code redeploy, no update columns table.

Comment: So you want to change what is returned without actually changing _anything_? You will either have to change your data or you will have to create code in the database to filter the data the way you describe (virtual private database could be one option). There's no way I can think of to do what you're asking without having to change _something_ in every database or table affected by this, or without changing your application code.

Comment: @pmdba Thank your comment

Comment: It is hard to follow exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  If you are adding changing the definition of `tbl_company_info` to add the equivalent of an `active_flag` column so that the table has both active and inactive rows, you can change the table name and then create a view on top of the table that returns only the active rows. which will be basically transparent to the application (there are a couple of exceptions).  But I'm not sure if that is the question you are really asking.

Comment: @JustinCave Thank you correct but to do that need time and cost. but it the best way and safe

Comment: What "time" and "cost" are you trying to avoid?  If you are literally trying to avoid making *any* change in any piece of code or anywhere in the configuration of the system, that's obviously impossible (you can't change behavior without changing something).  Renaming a table and creating a view with the old table name is a pretty minimal change.